# iCal Calendar - Using AppleScript how do I get the calendar's server address

Tags: applescript, calendar, ical

I am using my iCloud account and want to make sure the the calendar I am creating an event in is an iCloud calendar and not on my Mac.  Can't find the property that either tells me the account name or the server address of the calendar.

Comment: All I can give you is the caldav Address, which is caldav.icloud.com

Comment: Clarification- what if I have 2 calendars with the same name on different servers. How to know which is which?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the calendars enter information into the description field of the calendar that can be retrieved to differentiate servers.